A palavra 'rotacionar' é um neologismo do inglês 'rotate' ou já é reconhecida no português?
aqui no brasil. muitos professores e alunos usam o verbo rotacionar, mas a palavra não aparece em dicionários tradicionais. rotacionar é um neologismo?

Minha professora de pilates usa girar no lugar de rotacionar.

Qual seria o contexto?

Na física, o movimento pode ser translativo ou rotativo (sempre de acordo com um referencial). Rotacionar é usado para rotação como sinônimo de girar, já que a palavra 'rodar' é recorrente e não especializada.

O Vocabulário Oficial da Língua Portuguesa (VOLP), da Academia Brasileira de Letras, que traz as palavras reconhecidas na língua portuguesa, não registra a palavra "rotacionar".
Logo, por ora, o termo é sim considerado neologismo.

VOLP na verdade quer dizer «Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa».

Dada que a dicionarização de neologismos tipicamente é lenta, eu diria que, dado que "rotacionar" já está presente em vários dicionários estabelecidos (e.g., Houaiss, Priberam, Infopédia, o da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e Aulete), deve ser considerado um termo estabelecido.

Sobre sua etimologia, os dicionários dão o latim, por meio de rotação + -ar, mas buscas (pelo Jorge B. e por mim) encontram o uso mais antigo do termo em textos técnicos traduzidos do inglês, sugerindo que uma etimologia passando pelo "rotate" parece mais plausível.

Eu tenho o houaiss eletrônico e o verbete rotacionar não consta.

o verbewte rotacionar´também não está do dicionário da academia de Ciências de Lisboa. não est

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi O verbete consta no Houaiss online, como se vê no screenshot que adicionei. De qualquer forma, um verbete não precisa estar presente em uma infinidade de dicionários para contar como dicionarizado.

na minha versão do Houaiss  em CD que veio  junto com o dicionário em papel, o verbete não aparece.

@HumbertoJoséBortolossi Contactei a Academia e agora o verbete está incluído: https://dicionario.acad-ciencias.pt/pesquisa/?word=rotacionar

Só um aparte, fiz uma pesquisa, e esse termo começa a aparecer por volta dos anos 90, quase todos os registos que encontrei são de traduções de paper's de universidades norte-americanas.

@JorgeB. Sim, eu também não boto muita fé nas etimologias via "rotação" que dão, pode mesmo ser via inglês mesmo. Sua busca incluiu textos técnicos anteriores aos anos 1990?

Sim, encontrei alguns, poucos, antes de 1990. Acho que o mais antigo é de 1959, mais uma vez de uma tradução brasileira de um texto norte-americano.

@JorgeB. A origem via inglês de fato é verossímil, deveria ter feito antes, mas agora adicionei à resposta.
